# Select into variable

Tags: oracle

I would like to make my own name randomizer for a project using ORACLE and I have a table called `MOTHER_NAMES` with roughly 30 entries of varchar2 woman names.

```
declare
womanName varchar2;
select (select * from MOTHER_NAMES ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM desc fetch first 1 row only) FROM DUAL INTO womanName;
```

and I get this error which does not really help me what so ever.

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
>
> 933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

From my point of view all I'm doing is correct because if I only run this statement:

```
select (select * from MOTHER_NAMES ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM desc fetch first 1 row only) FROM DUAL;
```

I get a random name out of 30 entries with no problem, so my big question is why cant I also assign this name to the variable `womanName`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to work procedurally then you need to use PL/SQL. The snippet you show does not cover all the basics you need for an anonymous block in PL/SQL.
Try the following as a starter (I haven't run it but it should get you started.

```
DECLARE
  s_womanName  VARCHAR2(30);
BEGIN
  SELECT name
    INTO s_womanName
    FROM mother_name
  ORDER BY DBMS_RANDOM.RANDOM DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Random name - '||s_womanName);
END;
```

You might also get the result you want using SAMPLE;

```
SELECT name
  INTO s_womanName
  FROM mother_name SAMPLE (1)
WHERE ROWNUM < 2
```

Take a look at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/toc.htm for the PL/SQL basics.